# Bring template constants from backend and implement in frontend

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm learning in paralel a React Native course and NodeJS course. In the ReactJS course the "professor" showed how you can make in React Native a file with constants and distribute those constants where you will need.

In the frontend, React folder, I first set up a file with constants, constants.js:

```
export default {
  HOME_BACKGROUND_COLOR: '#e8e8e8',
  ALTERNATIVE_HOME_BACKGROUND_COLOR: '#313131',
  HOME_FONT_FAMILY: '"Open Sans", sans-serif',
  BORDER_COLOR: '#DDDDDD',
  WARNING_COLOR: '#FFF300',
  ALERT_COLOR: '#D52B1E',
}
```

Then in the one file that I need, a css file(but because we are in React Native is still js file) the constants, I import the file in the top and use them.

AppStyle.js

```
import constants from './constants'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 26,
    backgroundColor: HOME_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
    fontFamily: HOME_FONT_FAMILY,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-start"
  }
});
```

So this works. I tried to go by myself deeper with this and put in a database those constants. Senior friends told me that is better to have in backend those constants and from backend to change them, for example if you make a boilerplate for future projects.

So now I get from backend a json with all constants, same with the one that I had it in front end, but now is in backend.

I tried for almost a week to figure out how to put these constants from backend. I was thinking to put them in the Redux store, but I didn't see anyone putting connect() in the style files.

Please, believe I ran out of ideas. I guess I don't have enough experience. 
Someone please give me a little help.

UPDATE:
Following what you guys told me I made this:

in the App.js I put  to see them on the console.log.

```
render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      >
        <Constants />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

and in the constants.js:

```
const Constants = () => {
  getConstants = async () => {
    await fetch(environment.provider + `constants`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }).then(responseJSON => {
      console.log('responseJSON', JSON.stringify(responseJSON));
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('Was an error: ', error)
    })
  }
  return (
    <View>
      {getConstants()}
    </View>
  )
};

export default Constants;
```

But I get the error, on the this line: {getConstants()}

```
Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

that I have no idea what to do.

I did it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Api of constants response in JSON

```
{
    container:{
      "HOME_BACKGROUND_COLOR": 1,
      "ALTERNATIVE_HOME_BACKGROUND_COLOR": "tem2",
      "HOME_FONT_FAMILY": "934",
      "BORDER_COLOR": "#DDDDDD",
      "WARNING_COLOR": "#FFF300",
      "ALERT_COLOR": "#D52B1E"
    }
}
```

Stylesheet

```
export default Constants;

        import constants from './constants'

        const styles = StyleSheet.create({
          container: {
            flex: 1,
            padding: 26,
            backgroundColor: HOME_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
            fontFamily: HOME_FONT_FAMILY,
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "flex-start"
          }
        });
```

Code

```
import Constants from "./Constants"


        var apiResponse = {};

      getConstants = async () => {
        await fetch(environment.provider + `constants`, {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        }).then(responseJSON => {
          apiResponse = responseJSON;
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log('Was an error: ', error)
        })
      }



    ComponentWillMount(){
        super();
        getConstants();
    }    




    render() {
        return (
          <View style={[Constants.styles.container,apiResponse.container]}>
            {...}
          </View>
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the constants came from backend, it would become JSON. You have to `JSON.stringify(constants)` stringify the response from backend to use that constants in frontend.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe putting CSS variables in the backend is such a good idea. There are much better solutions to handle theming of an app.

One of them would be: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components.
With `styled-components` you could create multiple themes and utilize environment variables to switch between them if you would like.

Having your css in the backend requires you to make a request in order to get the essential styling of your app. Think of the scenario where the users connection is slow or if your backend crashes.

CSS should be handled by the client.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to get your constants from server using HTTP request in background which gives you JSON then you can use in your component styling on run time.

There are low chances of not getting your constants from server in case when server doesn't work or might some network connection issue, in that case you can use constants from front-end.

Comment: Instead of returning view in your main <View> tag, you are calling request which causes an error including an Object in JSX code.

Comment: Please my friend, if you know, tell me how to do that. I know React Native for only one month.